# In Studying the peoples of pre-Roman Britain, what are our primary reference sources?

Tags: britain, sources, celts

Where do we get our information on the people's of pre-Roman Britain?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehistoric_Britain: Because no literature of pre-Roman Britain has survived, its history, culture and way of life are **known mainly through archaeological finds**. The same article also mentiones outside (Roman) accounts, e.g. Avienus quoting "Ora Maritima" text and Avienus's records

Comment: You might want to take a look at the sources for the book: Death Of Kings.

Answer (score 5):

If the historian [Tacitus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacitus) simply provides too much of a [Roman perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacitus#Approach_to_history) and/or is too late in history (1st century AD), then [archaeological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Iron_Age#Archaeological_evidence) evidence is likely the best source (as DVK previously commented).

> **[The people of Iron Age Britain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Iron_Age#The_people_of_Iron_Age_Britain)**
>
> Demography The Roman historian described the Britons as being
>   descended from people who had arrived from the continent, comparing
>   the Caledonians (in modern-day Scotland) to their Germanic neighbours;
>   the Silures of Southern Wales to Iberian settlers; and the inhabitants
>   of Southeast Britannia to Gaulish tribes. This migrationist view long
>   informed later views of the origins of the British Iron Age and,
>   indeed, the making of the modern nations. Linguistic evidence inferred
>   from the surviving Celtic languages in Northern and Western Great
>   Britain at first appeared to support this idea, and the changes in
>   material culture which archaeologists observed during later prehistory
>   were routinely ascribed to a new wave of invaders.

**Other Resources:**

- [English Heritage Discover the Past](http://www.english-heritage.org.uk/daysout/properties/silchester-roman-city-walls-and-amphitheatre/history-and-research/iron-age-tribal-centre/) (The **Iron Age** town of Calleva)
- Iron Age Britain (English Heritage) `Author: Barry Cunliffe`